# What is the safest way to extract <title> from an HTML file using xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

Here is my current xpath code `"/html/head/title"`.

But you know, in the real world html environment, the code format usually broken, e.g. `<html>` tag is missing could cause an exception. So, I would like to know if there's a safe way to extract the `<title>` tag? (something like getElementByTagName)

Comment: Where is the code running, in the browser or elsewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to assume that an HTML page that is missing the `<html>` tag is also well-formed enough to be searchable through XPath.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`"//title"` perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Because of the unruly nature of html markup you should use an html parsing library. You didn't specify a platform or language but there are a number of [open source libraries out there.](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1SNNT_enUS377US377&q=open+source+html+parsing+library&aq=f&aqi=m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

Comment: You can use XPath *with* an HTML parsing library.  Html Agility Pack is just one example, of many, that supports both.

Comment: @Matthew: Good point. I qualified the xpath statement in my answer.

Comment: I don't get what "attempting xpath [...] directly on the markup" means.  XPath requires the markup is already parsed to a DOM.

Comment: @Matthew: Fair enough. I was making assumptions (such as some HTML->XML process) with very little context. Paring down the answer to just suggest the use of a library, which I supposed I'm assuming is not being used.

Answer (score 3):

Actually `/html/head/title` should work just fine, even on badly malformed mark-up, assuming:

- there is a title element;
- your HTML parser behaves the same way browser parsers do;
- your HTML parser puts the HTML elements into the null namespace.

You will have to allow for the possibility of there being multiple title elements in invalid HTML, so `/html/head/title[1]` is possibly better.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use javascript, you can do it:

```
document.title
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have something that an XML parser can parse (which is not the case with most HTML, but needs to be the case to use XPath), then you could use `//title` to get the  element.