# My importXML + xPath + Soundcloud playlist Not Working

Tags: xpath, import, google-docs, soundcloud

### So How To Use importXML By Google Docs Spreadsheet Plus xPath To Help Me Copy Soundcloud Playlist Track Title?

Today I'm looking for a solution on how to copy the Track Title of tracks inside a Soundcloud Playlist/Compilation.

I searched around and discovered importXML function offered by Google Docs Spreadsheet. While digging further about the `importXML` function, I discovered about `xPath`.

Great combination! I thought.

So I quickly get my hands on the tools and tested it, and it's great! I've extracted some data. And so I decided that I'm ready to implement the tool and use it with Soundcloud.

But when I tried to implement the syntax, I got an error saying `Import Internal Error`

#### The Syntax Is

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='sc-media-content']/a[@title]")
```

`<div class="sc-media-content">` is the div that holds the Track Title of the song, that is enclosed within an anchor tag with `title` attribute.

Here is the html block for it;

```
<div class="sc-media-content">
  <a class="soundTitle__title sc-link-dark sc-truncate " href="/seven-lions/velvetine-the-great-divide?in=thedubstepgod/sets/melodic-dubstep-chillstep" title="Velvetine - The Great Divide (Seven Lions Remix)">
  Velvetine - The Great Divide (Seven Lions Remix)
  </a>
```

What I'm trying to extract is the `Velvetine - The Great Divide (Seven Lions Remix)`. `A1` is the cell where the `Soundcloud Playlist Link` is pasted into.

#### Other Syntax I've Tried

I've tried other syntax too, like;

- `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='sc-media-content']/title")`
  As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508281/what-is-the-safest-way-to-extract-title-from-an-html-file-using-xpath)
- `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='sc-media-content']/@title")` From an answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973939/use-xpath-or-xquery-to-show-text-in-title-attribute), though it wasn't an accepted answer.

So what am I doing wrong? How could I copy those soundcloud playlist title to my Google Docs Spreadsheet using xPath?

### UPDATE

Based from the answer given by `TGH`, this should work `//div[@class='sc-media-content']/a/text()`.

But, the problem is that the div block that we're looking for is not in the source code. I did a `view source code` on the Playlist's page and the div block is not there. All I'm seeing is JavaScripts. So JS is loading the div blocks/classes.

#### So another question might be needed to help solve this one

How to use xPath with JavaScript loaded html elements?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
//div[@class='sc-media-content']/a/text()
```

Or if you want to grab it from the title do this

```
//div[@class='sc-media-content']/a/@title
```

I tested it here and it seems to work. Pasted your html, but had to close the div manually.

http://www.unit-testing.net/Xpath

Comment: Hm.. I tried it on the page suggested. I did however have to close the div manually before testing.

Comment: `//div[@class='sc-media-content']/a/text()` should work, based on the testing tool you've posted. Here's what I've found out by the way. When looking at the page's source code, the html block is not there. I mean, the code block that supposed to hold the `div class="sc-media-content` is not in the source code. So it must be loaded by JS, right?