# ImportXML + Selector Gadget(xPath) --> Soundcloud Followers to Google Sheets Not Working

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, soundcloud

I am trying to use =IMPORTXML and Xpath (Using the Selector Gadget Chrome extension since I am new to coding and XML is pretty daunting) to copy the number of followers of a given page to a Google Sheet. Ideally i would love to do this for thousands of accounts that i keep track of.

I have been following a guide which explained how to do this on [Twitter](https://techstunt.com/automatically-pull-in-data-to-your-google-spreadsheets/) and I am trying to adapt it to Soundcloud. My concerns are:

1. Selecting the right URL from which to source the information
2. Getting the right Xpath code

This is my entire code, which gets a formula parse error when executed on google sheets:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://soundcloud.com/codexnaturae", "//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "sc-border-light-right", " " )) and (((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 1) and parent::*)]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "sc-font-tabular-light", " " ))])")
```

Broken down:

1.URL

```
=IMPORTXML("https://soundcloud.com/codexnaturae",
```

2.X-Path as per Selector Gadget

[Selector Gadget Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcl7g.jpg)

`//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "sc-border-light-right", " " )) and (((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 1) and parent::*)]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "sc-font-tabular-light", " " ))]`

I have looked at [A similar issue but with radically different x-path and no shown on the post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600911/my-importxml-xpath-soundcloud-playlist-not-working)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even just pointing me in the right direction. Thank you so much in advance.